# DefaultApplicationLike Won't Work With AndroidStudio

Tags: android, buck, exopackage

I am setting up [Exopackage](https://buckbuild.com/article/exopackage.html#use-exopackage)

You need to extend your Application class from `DefaultApplicationLike` rather than `android.app.Application`.

The problem is 2 fold:

1. Extending from this class gives and error in the AndroidManfest.xml file where you need to assign `android:name=".App"`

> .App is not assignable to android.app.Application

2. Lifecycle hooks are lost. For example `attachBaseContext(Context base)` (from `Application`'s implementation of `ContextWrapper`)

My hope with Buck is that I can still use the Android Studio IDE.

Is there a way to make DefaultApplicationLike implement Application or another way to make exopackage work with an Android Studio project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to continue reading the guide. The next step is to create a new class that extends from `ExopackageApplication`. `ExopackageApplication` extends `android.app.Application` so if you use that in your `AndroidManifest.xml` it should work.

Comment: True. But it still doesn't have the life cycle hooks. attachBaseContext

Comment: Aggressor, yes it does: https://github.com/facebook/buck/blob/master/src/com/facebook/buck/android/support/exopackage/ExopackageApplication.java#L99, which also happens to be the same time when your new DefaultApplicationLike subclass gets created

Comment: `protected final void attachBaseContext(Context base)` They made the override final (where it passes the Context base which is the one I needed! Adding `final` lets me override it

Comment: @Aggressor - seriously? I linked you to the method you need to override. `onBaseContextAttached` gets called from the final `attachBaseContext`. Whatever code you had in `attachBaseContext`, move it to `onBaseContextAttached`. You can get the base context by calling `getBaseContext()`.